# css - rotate option not work in mobile

Tags: html, css

Hi i have some weird problem with rotate attribute in css.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="text-center our-services">
          <div class="row">

            {{#each info.cube}}            
            <div class="col-sm-4 flip-card wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                <div id="f1_container">
                  <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
                    <div class="front face">
                      <p class="title-serv">{{this.title}}</p>
                      <img src="{{this.img}}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="back face center">
                      {{this.info}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 170px;
  background: #028fcc;
  z-index: 1;
}

#f1_container {
  perspective: 1000;
}

#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}

#f1_card .front .title-serv {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#f1_card .front img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: silver;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

The problem is in the rotate
in the pc screen the code is great,
Has you can see in this web:

```
https://yaghobieh.herokuapp.com/
```

when do you arrive to this CUBES:

[image]

The flip don't work @ mobile.
Of course I can hidden and make another class withot flip, 
But I want to fix that.

Comment: Please add the code to your post, don't link to it.

Comment: Mobile doesnt have hover. It works when you click on them. At least when I try.

Comment: But the blue background don't work :(

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JavaScript instead CSS:

```
$('#f1_container').on('hover', '#f1_card', function(){
  css({
    transform: 'rotateY(180deg)',
  });
});
```

Or customize this for mobiles only:

```
if ( $(window).width() < 769 ) {
  $('#f1_container').on('hover', '#f1_card', function(){
    css({
      transform: 'rotateY(180deg)',
    });
  });
}
```